# Php Extension MySqli installed but calling it gives an error

Tags: php, docker, wordpress, mariadb

I run the following statements (so it is completely reproducible) (because i wanted to play with the source code of WordPress) and the following makes your current dir a website running under 8082 (pwd).

```
mkdir wordpress
cd wordpress
git clone https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git .
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 –name some-mariadb -e MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=PASSWORD -d mariadb:latest
docker run -d -p 8082:80 –mount type=bind,source=”$(pwd)”,target=/var/www/html php:apache
```

- In /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini extension=mysqli is uncommented (and uncommented others) (so i edited this file)
- I can connect to MariaDb and make databases and stuff

I make a new file: info.php:

```
if ( function_exists( 'mysqli_connect' ) ) 
{
   echo "exists";
}
else
{
   echo "does not exist";
}
phpinfo();
```

The problem: The output in the browser shows "does not exist".

[image]

(phpinfo() phpinfo shows the lib mysqlnd 8.0.11)
[image]

This means that WordPress gives the same Error since this the code that WordPress uses.

So why... can it not find the function / extension while phpinfo gives the details.

I do something wrong which could well be.

Ref:

- https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb official image
- https://hub.docker.com/_/php official image
- https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git official mirror repo

---

**update**
I noticed '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' was not in the phpinfo screen above.
So I unpacked the tar file (in the docker image ofcourse) and

- ran the same config command that phpinfo gave appended with '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' (but had to install in-between various apt-get xxx-dev libs including apache dev libs, libxml-dev, sqlite3-dev, libssl-dev,  zlib1g-dev, libcurl4-openssl-dev, libonig-dev, libreadline-dev, libsodium-dev, libargon2-dev)
- ran make
- ran make install
- restart

---

this solved the prob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this docker image php compilation a package is missing.

1. get inside the image and unpack the php tar
2. copy the config of phpinfo and append '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd'
3. install missing packages (various) xxx-dev libs including apache dev libs,
   libxml-dev, sqlite3-dev, libssl-dev, zlib1g-dev,
   libcurl4-openssl-dev, libonig-dev, libreadline-dev, libsodium-dev,
   libargon2-dev (with apt-get install xxx)
4. run make
5. run install
6. restart

And this will be solved.

Or... search for an image on docker hub that has this.